# move UITableView items from left to right

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I hope to move UITableView tiems fromn left to right and reload a new table array.
I know it can done by navigationcontroller.
But if there is a way without navigationcontroller.

Thanks
intterdev

Comment: Why you don't want to use navigation controller?

Comment: What about -reloadSections:withRowAnimation:?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can achieve same functionality by writing your custom animation code with two separate view controllers.

Load UITableView on one view controller and implement detail view in other view controller.

Now write your custom animation code for these two view controller.

Thanks,

Jim.